# How can I launch Task Manager and Explorer upon login while on a Domain?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Attempting to launch both of these application upon login into any server on the Domain. Placing these application in the StartUp folder would not be a solution since there are too many servers. Hopefully there is a solution out there...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a login script via a batch file to launch the programs (although Explorer will generally auto start anyway unless your running "headless").

Then in Active Directory point your Profile Logon Script to that batch file. It will run that batch file on any domain machine you logon to.

[image]

Comment: I've managed to add this in AD and place in the proper location on my DC. Here is what I trigger... 

C:\Windows\explorer.exe =

C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe

Thank you!

Comment: @GooSam20 you may need to allow replication time, and did it perform as you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using Group Policy Preferences.

Create a Group Policy and assign it to the servers that need to launch these apps on logon.

Under `Computer Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry` add `REG_SZ` entries to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` that point to the executables you want launched.

[image]

In your case, these executables:

```
C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe
C:\Windows\explorer.exe
```

Your newly added GPP registry entries should look something like this:

[image]